# How to validate for a set of characters in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, validation

I'd like to make a validation rule that prohibits the entry of certain characters in a given cell. For example, if my search set of characters are `("/","&","%")`, then I should get the following search results:

```
"Test, test" = false
"Te/st" = true
"Test...test&"= true
```

and the second two examples should not be allowed.

I guess I'm looking for something similar to SQL's WHERE...IN grammar.  How would I do this in Excel?  I know I can just use OR() or nested IF() statements, but I'm wondering if there's something cleaner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you're using Excel 2007, you could try something based on:

```
=IFERROR(FIND("%",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("&",A1),0)+IFERROR(FIND("/",A1),0)
```

which returns 0 if the string is valid and a positive number if it isn't.

if you're using 2003, then you'll need to change the IFERRORs into IF(ISERROR)s. e.g.

```
=IF(ISERROR(FIND("%",A1)),0,1)+IF(ISERROR(FIND("&",A1)),0,1)+IF(ISERROR(FIND("/",A1)),0,1)
```

which gives you 0 if the string is valid and 1 if it isn't.

Note: Your logic is negative (i.e. you're using TRUE for and error and FALSE for no error), but it's easy enough to reverse if you want to.

Comment: Return `>0` if the string is invalid, actually the number of invalid characters.  Surreond with `(...)>0` to return TRUE/FALSE (or `(...)=0` to invert the logic).  Can also be entered a bit more compactly as `=SUM(IF(ISERROR(FIND({"%","&","/"},A3)),0,1))>0`

Comment: This answer solves the problem as I stated it, but since I posted my question I've been thinking I'd like to find a solution that relies on a range to get the list of characters to search for.  That way I don't have to change the formula in every cell if I ever decide to change which characters I'm looking for.  Any ideas?

Comment: Chris' solution is better for that. He shows how to use a range of characters via an array formula.

Answer (score 1):

Heres another option

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A1,{"*%*","*&*","*/*"}))>0
```

To get the char list from a range:

If string to test is in A2, and list of char's is in A1:C1

```
=SUM(COUNTIF(A2,"*"&($A$1:$C$1)&"*"))>0
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use multiple find-calls. Test if it is a number, then it contains a forbidden character.

```
isnumber(find("/", cell)+find("%", cell)+find("&", cell))
```

**WRONG** - checks if all characters are in the cell. I've not testet the whole statement because my excel's got another localization and I've been to lazy. Should've been semi-colons, too. @Rhys Gibsons answer is correct, thanks @chris neilsen for hinting!

Comment: -1 Fails unless cell contains *all* of `?` `%` `&`